# I don't know how to explain but it is about limiting audio

Tags: premiere

How can I limit the audio up limit like this one in Premiere? Thanks in advice.

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  The waveform you pasted doesn't look like it would sound right at all.  Describe what you are trying to accomplish in terms of what the final output sounds like and we should be able to provide better direction.

Answer (score 2):

The second one looks hella clipped, isn't it distorting?

Anyway the effect you're after is unsurprisingly called a **limiter**. A limiter is a form of compressor, so a compressor can also be used, by setting the compression ratio high.

Premiere ships with a filter called **hard limiter**, and a compressor as well, but there are plenty more free and commercial VST [limiter plugins](http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2011/07/24/bpb-freeware-studio-best-free-limiter-vstau-plugins/) out there, and scads of [compressors](http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2012/02/18/bpb-freeware-studio-best-free-compressor-vstau-plugins/) if you want more knobs to twiddle.